# Deleting certain lines from a file using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

so I need to be able to remove certain lines from a text file based on the first word of that line.

I have tried `type file.txt | findstr /v %VAR% file.txt>file.txt` but that just clears the whole file.

I also tried

```
set /p VAR=word: 
type file.txt | findstr /v %VAR% file.txt>new_file.txt
del /q file.txt
ren new_file.txt file.txt
```

but I still get the same problem.
Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `type` and a pipe `|`, even though `findstr` could read the text file on its own? Simply use:

```cmd
findstr /V /I "^%VAR%\>" "file.txt" > "new_file.txt"
```

The `^` anchors the string to the beginning of the line, and the `\>` constitutes a word boundary as you want to match the first word.

In case `%VAR%` might also contain <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>, which separates multiple search strings, use this to keep the whole string as one search string:

```cmd
findstr /V /I /R /C:"^%VAR%\>" "file.txt" > "new_file.txt"
```

Remove the `/I` option if you want to do case-sensitive searching.

To overwrite the original file with the new one, just use:

```cmd
move /Y "new_file.txt" "file.txt" > nul
```